# RabbitMQ: check if message has been delivered?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

With a simple work queue, is is possible to ask the RabbitMQ server if a specific message has already been delivered to a consumer (worker) or if it is still in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query RabbitMQ about a specific message has been delivered, but if you you need to know if a message has been processed by a consumer you could use an RPC implementation to get a response sent back to the sender once your message has been processed.

You can find an example on how to implement a RPC solution on RabbitMQ's official tutorials [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).

Comment: Since I have a worker that can take a long time processing a job, I'd like to be able to know if it is currently being processed. I know I could send a message back at the beginning of the processing, but only the server knows when the worker dies unexpectedly. Anyway, I guess your answer ("you can't") is correct... :-(

Comment: Yea. It is a tricky to cover edge situations, but you could always leverage the RPC pattern to send a response from the consumer if something goes wrong, and if nothing goes wrong simply reply that the run was successful. This is of course impossible if the consumer itself crashes with an unexpected exception, or due to network or RabbitMQ issues.